# Use AAVE contract in my own contract. cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit

Tags: contract-invocation, ethers.js, contract-debugging, polygon, aave

I am tring to use AAVE contract in my own contract. but I have a question on this mysterious error.  `Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string", method="estimateGas"` Anyone knows what is the issue?

My sol contract is

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import {IPool} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/interfaces/IPool.sol";


contract MyContract{
    address private owner;
    constructor(){
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function submitOrder(address pool, address token, uint256 amount, address user) public payable{
        IPool(pool).supply(token, amount, user, 0);
    }
}
```

In my deployment file (ts file), I use

```
let contractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract");
let contract = await contractFactory.deploy();
```

In my script file, I use

```
let depositAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther("1");
let contractSigner = await contract.connect((await ethers.getSigners())[0]);
let (await contractSigner.submitOrder(poolAddress, tokenAddress, depositAmount, payerAddress)).wait();
```

I tested in my local network (Polygon) and I confirmed that I have enough token in my payerAddress.

```
payerAddress = "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266";
tokenAddress = "0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270";
poolAddress = "0x794a61358D6845594F94dc1DB02A252b5b4814aD";
```

Comment: I don't remember how Aave works, but I feel like the tokens need to be in `MyContract`, and it needs to approve the pool as spender.

Comment: May I ask what it mean tokens need to be in `MyContract`?

Comment: The underlying `token`. Aave pulls it from `msg.sender`, which is your contract. So the tokens must be owned by your contract, not `payerAddress`. payerAddress is only the recipient of the aTokens (afaik)